# ng-controller doesn't work for kendo tabstrip tab content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-tabstrip

ng-controller doesn't work for kendo tabstrip tab content. Please check my code below.

```js
<!--tabstripCtrl.js-->
angular.module('tabstripApp',[]);

var app = angular.module('tabstripApp');

app.controller('tabCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $('#tabstrip').kendoTabStrip({
    contentUrls:[
      'views/gridview1.html',
      'views/gridview2.html',
      'views/gridview3.html',
    ]
  });
}]);

<!--grid1Ctrl.js-->    
var app = angular.module('tabstripApp');

app.controller('grid1Ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.grid1 = "grid1";
}]);
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kendo.common.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/tabstripCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/gridCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="tabstripApp" ng-controller='tabCtrl'>
    <div id='tabstrip'>
        <ul>
            <li class="k-state-active">grid1</li>
            <li>grid2</li>
            <li>grid3</li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-controller="grid1Ctrl"></div>
        <div ng-controller="grid2Ctrl"></div>
        <div ng-controller="grid3Ctrl"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<!--gridview1.html-->
<div>
  <span>{{grid1}}</span>
</div>
```

Since each tab content is very complex, so I create separate html file to maintan them. But, the grid1Ctrl, grid2Ctrl and grid3Ctrl binding don't work, any ideas?

Comment: because you have not defined them

Comment: @Sajeetharan hi, updated, I haven't upload the tab content's view and controller before, but I defined them.

Comment: i think you are missing something, can you create a plunker

Comment: @Sajeetharan hi, there're some reasons that I can't upload a demo code. I have edited the question again, that's enough to reproduce the issue. Any ideas? Thannks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div id="tabstrip" kendo-tab-strip="tabstrip">
      <ul>
        <li class="k-state-active">grid1</li>
        <li>grid2</li>
        <li>grid3</li>
      </ul>
      <div ng-controller="grid1Ctrl">
        {{grid1}}
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="grid2Ctrl">
        {{grid2}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wzAvBIig5rql9K152Dvu?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks, I know this works. But I don't want to put tab content in the index file directly, because each of the contents are very complex, it will make the index file very large. So I use ContentUrls to load the content from different files. The controller binding doesn't work for separate content files. You can repro the issue through my post code.

Comment: @Allen4Tech then you need to use route mechanism. check the sample http://plnkr.co/edit/peXM2XSosnWnBgmp1fty?p=preview

Comment: thanks! But how to prevent the selected path display in url?

Comment: you can configure the url parameter in route, mark as answer if it has helped